Windows 10 boot failing after Win/Linux dual-boot migration to new SSD
Following this tutorial (without encryption), I copied/cloned all SSD partitions from my old 256 GB NVME SSD to a new 4 TB NVME SSD. Having then replaced the old with the new SSD in the Notebook, Grub as well as Linux start just fine. However, when I select Windows from the boot list, I obtain a blue recovery screen (German text), telling me the PC needs to be repaired and showing error code 0xc000000e.
Is there a way to repair this, preferably without the need for a Windows installation medium? I have the old SSD plugged via USB and would like to copy once again the relevant partition(s) to the (new) internal SSD. Could someone please assist in choosing the right tools/commands for that task?
For the old SSD (USB-plugged), parted -l gives me
Gerät         Anfang      Ende  Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sdb1       2048    206847    204800  100M EFI-System
/dev/sdb2     206848    239615     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3     239616 251850751 251611136  120G Microsoft Basisdaten
/dev/sdb4  498020352 500117503   2097152    1G Windows Recovery
... Linux stuff

and for the new SSD (internal):
Gerät              Anfang       Ende   Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/nvme0n1p1       2048    2099199    2097152    1G EFI-System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    2099200    2131967      32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    2131968  421562367  419430400  200G Microsoft Basisdaten
... Linux partitions/swap
/dev/nvme0n1p8 7811936256 7814035455    2099200    1G Windows-Recovery

Sorry for the German outputs. I remember having created nvme0n1p1 (EFI), nvme0n1p3 (Win installation) and nvme0n1p8 (Win recovery) partitions with Gparted and used rsync -avhP for file transfer. But for nvme0n1p2 (MS reserved) i used dd because I had issues when trying Gparted partition cloning or simple copying. BTW, I set the EFI partition size to 1 GB.
Which of these partitions is actually causing the Win boot error? And how would I re-transfer it to the new SSD? That should be possible without a live medium at all I assume.
Many thanks!

Probably need Windows tools. But by creating new ESP, you created new UUIDs & GUIDs. UEFI uses GUID/partUUID to know what ESP to boot from. Compare these. lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,uuid,partuuid with all partitions mounted. Compare to sudo efibootmgr -v The partuuid should match entry in UEFI. If not you can create new entry for Widnows, but you may need BCD repairs also which you only can do from Windows repair/recovery drive or installer''s recovery tools.

Note that Microsoft reserved is just unformatted space with GUID partition type set to Microsoft Reserved. Order on drive is important: msftres MSR
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition
Windows technical info on gpt and GUIDs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365449

Many thanks @oldfred for the valuable hints! is it possible to set the relevant partition UUIDs of the new SSD to the same UUIDs as the old SSD? For instance, Gparted allows to modify UUIDs. Would that help? I will have a look tomorrow ..

It looks like the x menu or advanced menu has a change guid. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html But I would backup both drive's partition tables before any change. sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sdX > backup_sdC.txt for both drives  and save to another drive. Looks like it includes UUID and parttype but not partuuid.

I would try to boot Windows directly before anything else. There's a chance it might work. I've done the same many times and could boot Windows directly afterwards. Then, it being some Ubuntu iteration + Windows, just run sudo update-grub from the Linux side.
